# PHP Soap request format differences

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap

We have a site built in Zend Framework and we're using the Zend Soap client.

I'm having trouble with one of the soap requests:
It's expecting data in this form

```
        <CustomerForm>
            <CustomerFormRow>
                <CuisineType>3</CuisineType>
                <CuisineRestaurant>True</CuisineRestaurant>
                <NumberOfStaff>801</NumberOfStaff>
                ...
```

But the soap client is generating the following

```
        <customerform>
            <ns2:map>
                <item>
                    <key>CuisineType</key>
                    <value>Greek</value>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <key>CuisineRestaurant</key>
                    <value>Cafe</value>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <key>NumberOfStaff</key>
                    <value>11 to 20</value>
                </item>
                ...
```

When using

```
$_processFormWS->processFormWS($session_id, $customer_id, $form_data);
```

So the service isn't handling the data I'm sending!

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that if I pass my $form_data as an object (rather than an array which it was before) then it works!

So:

```
$_processFormWS->processFormWS($session_id, $customer_id, (object) $form_data);
```

Would fix the above code.